# Ctrl + shift + right arrow stopped working, show error as Extended Chart Range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, charts

I have an issue with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>right arrow</kbd> stopped working. It had been working before, then one day I selected the default Add-ins to display on Excel (under Daniel's XL Toolbox NG tab on Excel menu, but the add-ins are default Excel add-ins), nothing happened, then the next time I tried to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>right arrow</kbd>, an error message appeared:

> Extended Chart Range: To use the Extended Chart range function, you need to have a chart!

I tried to de-select the Add-ins, but that does not fix the issue. —
I am using Excel 2010 on Windows 7 professional. I have Daniel's XL Toolbox NG installed as an Add-in for Excel, and I also have JMP and Acrobat add-ins for Excel, but I don't have any default add-ins open or checked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ling, please use the EDIT button to add information to your questions. It should not be necessary to read through comments to find your entire question.

Comment: thanks for reminder and I edited my post. First-time user.